# IFrame is getting updated on partial postback in webform asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a user control in that i have a iframe inside of update-panel and repeater.
and i am using that user control on page level where the user control is inside the update panel. Please suggest any structure change so i can achieve the requirement.

Following is the user control code.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" style="height: 100%">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div >
            <asp:Repeater ID="asp:Repeater " runat="server" OnItemDataBound="asp:Repeater _ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="item text-center" data-id="<%#Eval("ID") %>">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" class="img-responsive" />
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div class="responsive-wrapper responsive-wrapper-wxh-572x612" id="divIFrameWrapper" runat="server" style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow: auto;">
                                    <iframe id="iframe" runat="server" scrolling="yes"
                                        frameborder="0" class="img-responsive"
                                        allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**My requirement is:** Not to update the Iframe src on page postback.

Comment: you forgot to mention either what your requirement actually is, or really a clear description of the problem you're getting. Are you saying you don't want the iFrame to be updated when the rest of the content is? Not much you can do about that if the iframe tag is within your update panel - all the content in the panel is destroyed and replaced with new HTML from the server. So of course at that time the browser will create a new iframe tag and fetch the data for it from its source. If you don't want it to get updated, you'd have to move it outside your update panel.

Comment: ok, so the src of the iframe is probably set server-side, or do you just fill it with DOM elements? and what should happen/not happen now?

Comment: @dlatikay yes the src is setting from server side.

Comment: we don't even know what kind of web app this really is - webforms? asp.net, core?

Comment: it is in webforms.

Comment: so on *page* postback, everything is reloaded anyway. updatepanels or not. on partial postback, that's a different story. but only to make that clearer: is your problem that the iframe reloads its content page when the container page refreshes, or does it lose the value of its src property and come up empty?

Comment: @dlatikay yes the iframe src is gets reloaded on partial postback.

Comment: that's because, technically, the iframe is not reloading, it's being destroyed and re-created. I explained the reason already - see my earlier comment. If you don't want that to happen, then you have to move it outside your updatepanels (same as with any other HTML element)